# How to locate the span element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to locate the below element :

```
<span class="btn btn-default" onclick="close_terms_window();" style="" xpath="1">Next</span>
```

using selenium webdriver. But  I was getting this message:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='terms-modal']/div//*[@id='acceptterms']//*[@onclick="close_terms_window();"]"}
>     (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

I used the below methods:

**Method 1:**

```
time.sleep(4) 
element_term = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='terms-modal']/div//* [@id='acceptterms']//span[@onclick=\"close_terms_window();\"]")
```

**Method 2:**

```
element_term = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(@class,'btn') and contains(@class,'btn-default)]")))`
```

**Method 3:**

```
time.sleep(1)
element_term = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='terms-modal']/div//*[@id='acceptterms']//*[@onclick=\"close_terms_window();\"]")
```

**Method 4:**

Using CSS selector:

```
time.sleep(4)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.btn btn-default")
element_term = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(@class,'btn') and contains(@class,'btn-default)]")))
```

Source Code snapshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tib3V.png

Comment: Apologies for the messy format . I am new to stackoverflow. Please ignore the formatting .

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried with  `//span[.='Next' and @class=' btn btn-default']`?

Comment: Thank You . Yeah i tried but now luck . Getting the below error:           
 Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[.='Next' and @class=' btn btn-default']"}

Comment: //span[@class='btn btn-default'] try with this it will work.

Comment: That's great ! //span[@class='btn btn-default'] works fine . Earlier I tried the same without sleep  , now i tried with sleep so this works fine now . Is there any other way to avoid sleep as it's not good practice . In case of explicit wait which expected condition would work?

Comment: @charanyachinnasamy it clearly depends on your elements and what you want to perform. like for click we can use "EC.element_to_be_clickable"

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='btn btn-default')))
```

**Expected Conditions :**

These are some common conditions which are frequently used when automating web applications.

Selenium Python binding provides some convenience methods so you don’t have to code an expected_condition class yourself or create your own utility package for them.

- title_is
- title_contains
- presence_of_element_located
- visibility_of_element_located
- visibility_of
- presence_of_all_elements_located
- text_to_be_present_in_element
- text_to_be_present_in_element_value
- frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it
- invisibility_of_element_located
- element_to_be_clickable

Answer (score 0):

As the element is within a *Modal Dialog Box* to locate and click on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.btn.btn-default[onclick^='close_terms_window']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='btn btn-default' and starts-with(@onclick,'close_terms_window')][contains(., 'Next')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```